# Return an image from asp.net web api core as IActionResult

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What is the best way to return an image file as IActionResult while using asp.net web api core?
I tried returning a base64 string and it works fine. But not considered as efficient. 
Is there a way using which we can return an image file object itself as IActionResult.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the various overloads of the `File()` function in controllers that inherit from `Controller` or `ControllerBase`.

For example, you can do:

```
return File("~/Images/photo.jpg", "image/jpeg");
```

This uses a virtual path, other options include giving it a byte array or a `Stream`. You can also give a download file name as a third argument if that is needed.

Comment: my images are stored as base64 strings read from database. How may i server them directly from the Web API core as image/png

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question.

Comment: i have, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860069/return-base64-encoded-images-directly-from-a-web-api-core-endpoint

Answer (score 7):

```
[Route("getProductImage/v1")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getProductImage(GetProductImageQueryParam parammodel)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            MNimg_URL = MNimg_URL + parammodel.modelname;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(MNimg_URL);
            byte[] content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            //return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(content);
            return File(content, "image/png", parammodel.modelname);
        }
    }
```

In .net core web api you can use the above code

here GetProductImageQueryParam is a class with input parameters

Answer (score 7):

A `File` result is called `FileContentResult` in NET Core 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

You can return image using return file with **stream** or **bytes format** or using its **image path**.

There are few overloaded methods for `return File(//parameters);` which you can use it in mvc controller's action method.

> API Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FileController : Controller {

    //GET api/file/id
    [HttpGet("{id}"]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string id) {
        var stream = await {{//__get_stream_here__//}};
        var response = File(stream, "application/octet-stream"); // FileStreamResult
        return response;
    }    
}
```

or

```
var imageFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("// image path");
return File(imageFileStream, "image/jpeg");
```

Hope this will help you.