# Return an image and display in UI using Web API core and Angular 7

Tags: angular, image, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to display image in UI.

Here is my ASP.NET Web API Core Code for that.

```
    [Route("{id:int}/image")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(int id)
    {
        var data = await this.designService.GetImageAsync(id);

        byte[] result = data.Data;

        return this.File(result, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

I followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038912/return-an-image-from-asp-net-web-api-core-as-iactionresult) I assume above code is correct(Not sure if there is a better way to return Image - please guide me)

In component, my code looks like this.

```
this.service.getImageThumbnail(id).subscribe(
  baseImage => {
    this.thumbnail = baseImage;
  },
  error => (this.errorMessage = error)
);
```

In Service, implementation is like this

```
getDesignThumbnail(id: number) {
return this.http
.get(`https://localhost:44314/api/designs/${id}/thumbnail`)
.pipe(catchError(error => this.errorHandler(error)));
```

}

In HTML, I am displaying like this.(Not sure if this is correct)

```
 <img width="100" height="100" data-bind="attr: { src: thumbnail }" />
```

I am getting this error message 
[image: Error]

Comment: Add the `getImageThumbnail` implementation

Comment: added the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return dynamic object in Web API and change way to show image in angular.

I used this way to display image from API.

```
[Route("{id:int}/image")]
    public async Task<dynamic> GetImage(int id)
    {
        var data = await this.designService.GetImageAsync(id);

        byte[] result = data.Data;

        return new { Image = result}
    }
```

In service add `private sanitizer: DomSanitizer` to constructor.

```
this.service.getImageThumbnail(id).subscribe(
  baseImage => {
    let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + baseImage.Image;

    this.thumbnail = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
  },
  error => (this.errorMessage = error)
);
```

Updated:
I create a demo reading a jpeg image from base64 format stored json file.

Please check your image is png or jpeg in `data:image/png` or `data:image/jpeg`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-image-from-api

Comment: still not displaying, Is there anything related to image size. the string looks very big when I put breakpoint at objectURL. objectURL has value but thumbnail is null