# load files from backend

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm using Angular with ASP.NET core 3.0  and kind of new,
I've a function that save pdf files in the Backend asp.net in a Folder "Resources\PdfFiles"

I got upload function to work fine, and it saves the files and it gives me the url of "Resources\PdfFiles" back, which is ok, but how do I display the pdf file from the FrontEnd, like is there any function, that I can retrieve the files from "Resources\PdfFiles"

I just wanted to create a button, when a user click on it, it displays the pdf

would you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The way to view PDF file is same with Image file.

You need change `data:image/png` to `data:application/pdf`

I have answer for display image file using Web API, you can refer at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55324972/4964569

```
[Route("{id:int}/image")]
    public async Task<dynamic> GetImage(int id)
    {
        var data = await this.designService.GetImageAsync(id);

        byte[] result = data.Data;

        return new { Image = result}
    }
```

In service add `private sanitizer: DomSanitizer` to constructor.

```
this.service.getImageThumbnail(id).subscribe(
  baseImage => {
    let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + baseImage.Image;

    this.thumbnail = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
  },
  error => (this.errorMessage = error)
);
```

Comment: where you got designService from ?

Comment: you can defined yourself, in GetImageAsync() you read folder to get image content

Comment: doesn't the pdf saved in static wwwroot folder, so why can't i pull it from the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved your file in wwwroot, just refer to your physical file in this way:

```
 window.open(
     '/Resources/PdfFiles/yourpdfname.jpg',
      '_blank',
    );
```

Comment: it's been saved in the wwwroot, still won't u work when I try to do it on the client side..

Comment: Have you added app.UseStaticFiles(); in your startup?

Comment: I did, and added your code to the client side, when I click on it, it opens, localhost:4200/wwwroot\resources\pdfFiles\names.pdf

Comment: which won't open

Comment: wwwroot shouldn't be in the address, your path should be like below:localhost:4200/resources/pdfFiles/names.pdf

Comment: cause it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: `<tr *ngFor="let pd of AllPDFs; let i = index"> 
               <td>
          {{pd.docPath}} 
            
          <button (click)="OpenPath(pd.docPath)"> here  </button>

           </td>`

Comment: this for the html client side

Comment: ts file like this 
`public OpenPath= (serverPath: string) => {




window.open("http://localhost:4200/"+JSON.parse(serverPath).dbPath);  
  }
`

Comment: it takes the path from the use input

Comment: the task is to save pdf file into the wwwroot folder, and able to retrieve it from the client side and display it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216408/discussion-between-mohammad-niazmand-and-ayay).